# Failed to upload a file to ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, scp

I'm a newbie and all I want is to set up an ec2 instance for fever rss.
Here is my info: os x 10.9.2, aws with ami of ubuntu 12.04 lts. I set up lamp on ec2 following this guide: http://www.robotmedia.net/2011/04/how-to-create-an-amazon-ec2-instance-with-apache-php-and-mysql-lamp/

Now I can ssh to my server public IP using terminal. After connected the server, I typed

```
scp -i /path/to/keypair.pem /path/to/test.txt ubuntu@theServerPublicIP:~/
```

and got the error as follows:

```
Warning: Identity file keypair.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.
```

I have tried to resolve the problem by:
1. change permission of .pem file to 600 on my os x.

```
chmod 600 keypair.pem
```

and ssh again, scp again, and got same error. Then I change its permission to 400 on my os x,

```
chmod 600 keypair.pem
```

and redid ssh and scp, and got same error.

1. rewrite file path using ~/path/to/file for both of keypair.pem and test.txt, and then redid ssh and scp, got same error.
   Next rewrite file path using /Users/myUserName/path/to/file for both files and redid ssh and scp, got same error.
   Next cd to the folder of keypair.pem and test.txt (I put them in the same folder), and tried the above two naming and got same error for each.
2. change path on the server. I have tried "~","~/","/","/var/www/", for all I still got the same error.
3. I also tried forklift because I saw the developer of Fever using it in the demo video. I tried all options for connection: sftp... but couldn't connect to the server.

Please help to get the test.txt uploaded... then I will be able to upload the fever folder.

Thanks!

Comment: Warning: Identity file keypair.pem not accessible: No such file or directory. have you checked if the files is present on the ec2 instance on that path

Comment: @GhostRider Hi, I only have keypair.pem on my Mac. Do you mean that I should have a copy of keypair.pem on the server before I can scp?

Comment: yes...you trying to scp to a server after ssh as per your qsn, when you are on a instance the keys should be made available in /home/ubuntu/.ssh and should be refrenced from here

Comment: you need to check if the .pem file is on the path you mention in the command, and also if you have write permissions on the remote dir (where you try to upload your file).

Comment: Thanks chmod 600 worked for me...i was using chmod 400 for my pem file. BTW did you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you gotta do this frequently I advise you to create an alias.

For example: I was running a webserver on EC2 instance and I had HTML contents in a local dir `awsplaywww`

`$ alias syncaws="rsync -avrz --delete /home/sanket/workspace/awsplaywww/ -e ssh sanket@awsplay1.ddns.net:/var/www/html/"`

Now everytime I update a HTML file or something and need to send it back to server. I just open terminal and type `syncaws` and job done!